# Best way to redirect user in login.aspx page webforms try to access a page without access

Tags: url, redirect, authentication, action

I'm with a question.

Imagine, my web site is restricted in some URLs,
in a login page i try to access a url than i dont have permition

And if i doesnt i need to redirect to default page.

which is the best choice to do?

TY

Answer (score 0):

is some attribute or element than i can put on webconfig than for users without permission to access that location redirects to default page?

Comment: You should be editing your original question for this, instead of adding answers each time. Or alternatively you can add comments to your question.

Answer (score 0):

solved.

In login.aspx.cs pageload

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                if (Request.IsAuthenticated && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]))
                {
                    // This is an unauthorized, authenticated request...
                    Response.Redirect("YOUR_PAGE_URL");
                }
            }
        }